# G_DEFINE_TYPE error

Tags: gtk

In my gtk+ application i have following code:

```
G_DEFINE_TYPE(PicFile, pic_file, G_TYPE_OBJECT)
```

When i try to compile it i see error:
**error:invalid application of sizeof to incomplete type 'PicFileClass'**

Where PicFileClass -

```
typedef struct _PicFileFileClass PicFileClass;

struct _PicFileClass {
    GObjectClass parent;
};
```

What's wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In your first line you have `_PicFileFileClass`, while later it becomes `_PicFileClass`.